# AngularJS Not Setting Correct Content-Type In Http POST

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js

So I am trying to upload an mp3 file to a NodeJS server. I am seeing the file data and everything correctly, so I know my model is right, but every time I send the http post, I get an invalid JSON error. This is confusing because I have set the content-type to both undefinded and multipart/form-data and regardless when I look into the console I still see that in the request header the content-type is set to application/json. Here is the code I am using to do the upload:

Template:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label name="type-label" for="type">Type</label>
    <select name="type" ng-model="data.type">
      <option value="music">Music</option>
      <option value="image">Image</option>
      <option value="video">Video</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label name="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="data.name" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label name="description-label" for="description">Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" ng-model="data.description" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="file" upload-file="file"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="upload()">Select File</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Service:

```
angular.module('app').factory("UploadService", ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      upload: function (file, data) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        return $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/upload/' + data.type,
          data: fd,
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        })
        .success(function(){
          //Do something.
        })
        .error(function(){
          //Do something.
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('UploadController', ['$scope', 'UploadService',
  function($scope, UploadService) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.upload = function() {
      console.log($scope.file);
      UploadService.upload($scope.file, $scope.data);
    };
  }
]);
```

In the end I even wrote a little helper config to try and force the default content-type for http posts.

Helper:

```
angular.module('app').config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = { 'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data' };
});
```

At this point I am pretty stuck on what to do, so any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated. Or any tips on uploading MP3s in general if there is an easier way than this. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting ``multipart/form-data`` for content-type when i tried your code .  What issue you are facing ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your content-type in your service like this:

```
angular.module('app').factory("UploadService", ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      upload: function (file, data) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        return $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/upload/' + data.type,
          data: fd,
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
          }
        })
        .success(function(){
          //Do something.
        })
        .error(function(){
          //Do something.
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```